# Proving the following statements about dimension of subspaces are equivalent, quotient spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$U, V$ are subspaces of vector space $A$, not necessarily finite dimensional. The proposition is that the following statements are equivalent.

1. $dim((U+V)/(U\cap V)) <\infty$
2. $dim(U/(U\cap V))<\infty$ and $dim(V/(U\cap V))<\infty$
3. $dim((U+V)/U)<\infty$ and $dim((U+V)/V)<\infty$

I don't know where to start, are there theorems that should be referred to? I am unfamiliar with these types of problems, can someone provide one implication?

Answer (score 1):

$1.\implies 2.$

Since $U/(U\cap V)\subset (U+V)/(U\cap V)$ and $V/(U\cap V)\subset (U+V)/(U\cap V)$, We have
$$
\dim{U/(U\cap V)}\leqslant \dim{(U+V)/(U\cap V)}
$$
$$
\dim{V/(U\cap V)}\leqslant \dim{(U+V)/(U\cap V)}
$$
$2.\implies 3.$

By Second Ring Isomorphism Theorem (vector space is also ring), there is
$$
U/(U\cap V)\simeq (U+V)/V)\quad\text{and }\quad V/(U\cap V)\simeq (U+V)/U)
$$
So we have
$$
\dim{U/(U\cap V)}=\dim{(U+V)/V}\quad\text{and }\quad \dim{V/(U\cap V)}=\dim{(U+V)/U}
$$
$3.\implies 1.$

Since
$$
\dim{U/(U\cap V)}=\dim{(U+V)/V}\quad\text{and }\quad \dim{V/(U\cap V)}=\dim{(U+V)/U}
$$
we have
$$
\dim{U/(U\cap V)}<\infty\quad\text{and }\quad \dim{V/(U\cap V)}<\infty
$$
Moreover
$$
(U+V)/(U\cap V)\subset U/(U\cap V)+V/(U\cap V)
$$
Thus
$$
\dim{(U+V)/(U\cap V)}\leqslant \dim{U/(U\cap V)}+\dim{V/(U\cap V)}<\infty
$$

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer, can you explain why $U/(U\cap V)\subset(U+V)/(U\cap V)$? I think everything else makes sense

Comment: That is for $U\subset U+V$